# How to match string patterns with special charectors (è)

Tags: .htaccess, pattern-matching, special-characters

In my site I have some URLs with special characters like `è`. How should check URL pattern matching for those kind URLs in `.htaccess` file?

`([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)` used for check normal characters URL pattern matching. How should I check that kind of special characters in this kind of URL pattern match? ex: string like `suède`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can match **`è`** using:

`^(.*)è(.*)$`